# Shell Context Menu Commands for Kindle Files Only Showing for Certain Extensions

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu, file-types, context

A while ago, I added a number of context menu commands to import Kindle books into Calibre and convert them to EPUB (under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Amazon.Kindle.content).  All associated extensions are set in the registry to point at Amazon.Kindle.content.  This has been working great up until today, when the commands stopped showing up for .mobi files.  When I right click a .azl, .azs, .azw, .azw3, .azw4, .prc or .tpz file, they appear and work as expected.  But not for .mobi.  Here are my registry entries for .azw and .mobi — they look exactly the same to me so I have no idea what is going on:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.azw]
@="Amazon.Kindle.content"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mobi]
@="Amazon.Kindle.content"

jscholes@rebus:~$ cat >azw.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.azw]
@="Amazon.Kindle.content"

jscholes@rebus:~$ cat >mobi.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mobi]
@="Amazon.Kindle.content"

jscholes@rebus:~$ diff azw.reg mobi.reg
3c3
< [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.azw]
---
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mobi]
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting and re-creating the keys for mobi? Did you install anything recently that might have associated itself with the extension?

Comment: Yes.  So far, I've tried: Deleting and recreating HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mobi; doing the same for other Kindle-related file extensions; removing and restoring my additional commands in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Amazon.Kindle.content; and reinstalling Kindle for PC (which creates the file associations in the first place).  In Windows Explorer, when focussed on a .mobi file the Type column shows "MOBI File."  When focussed on a file with any of the (working) extensions it shows "Amazon Content."  I don't understand why .mobi files aren't being appropriately associated.

Comment: See my own answer.  I don't really understand why that solution worked, but glad the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, which I probably should've tried sooner, was to set the default program for .mobi files to Kindle for PC.  Nothing has been altered in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.mobi after doing this, but the commands now show when right-clicking a .mobi file.